# how to send more then 1 EditText value using bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, back

I have made a simple android program with two activities,in that 1st activity contains some edittexts and a button,and second activity contain same number of textviews.Now when the button in 1st activity pressed the text from Edittexts should go to 2nd activity's textViews.I have tried code as below,but it's not working:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public  String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myweb";
     Button b;
     EditText ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         b =(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
         ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg);
         ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg1);
         ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg3);
         ed4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg4);


                 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);
                     Bundle b=new Bundle();
                     String fname=ed1.getText().toString();
                     String lname=ed2.getText().toString();
                     String fon=ed3.getText().toString();
                     String city= ed4.getText().toString();

                     b.putString("Extra__fname", fname);
                     b.putString("Extra__lname", lname);
                     b.putString("Extra__fon", fon);
                     b.putString("Extra__city", city);

                     i.putExtras(b);
                     startActivity(i);



                     /*i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", s);
                         startActivity(i);*/

                     }
                 });

    }

}
```

**Act2.java**

package com.example.myweb;

```
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Act2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);

         Intent i = getIntent();

         Bundle b =i.getExtras();
         String fname=i.getStringExtra("fname");
         String lname=i.getStringExtra("lname");
         String fon=i.getStringExtra("fon");
         String city=i.getStringExtra("city");



        // String text = i.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            TextView t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);

            t.setText(fname);
            t1.setText(lname);
            t2.setText(fon);
            t3.setText(city);



    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
05-10 15:09:07.877: W/KeyCharacterMap(1072): No keyboard for id 0
05-10 15:09:07.877: W/KeyCharacterMap(1072): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-10 15:09:16.976: D/AndroidRuntime(1072): Shutting down VM
05-10 15:09:16.976: W/dalvikvm(1072): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listdemo/com.example.listdemo.SecondActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.example.listdemo.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:22)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-10 15:09:16.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: in Act2 get bundle values , b.getStringExtra("fname"); , not use "i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**strong text**   Try:

```
     Bundle b =i.getExtras();
     String fname=b.getStringExtra("fname");
     String lname=b.getStringExtra("lname");
     String fon=b.getStringExtra("fon");
     String city=b.getStringExtra("city");
```

**This will also work:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);
i.putExtra("Extra__fname", fname);
i.putExtra("Extra__lname", lname);
i.putExtra("Extra__fon", fon);
i.putExtra("Extra__city", city);
startActivity(i);
```

**Then in your activity2:**

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null)
    {
      fname= bundle.getString("Extra__fname");
      lname= bundle.getString("Extra__lname");
      fon= bundle.getString("Extra__fon");
      cit= bundle.getString("Extra__city");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using different name while sending values and retrieving values.

```
b.putString("Extra__fname", fname);
b.putString("Extra__lname", lname);
b.putString("Extra__fon", fon);
b.putString("Extra__city", city);
```

You are sending fname using Extra__fname and retrieving it using fname.
Similiarly in other cases also.

```
String fname=i.getStringExtra("fname");
String lname=i.getStringExtra("lname");
String fon=i.getStringExtra("fon");
String city=i.getStringExtra("city");
```

Keep names same at both places.

Comment: Did this solution work? If yes, please click on Accept the answer else share your problem here.